# Shared Memory giving ambiguous results

Tags: linux, shared-memory

I was trying to communicate between two processes using Shared Memory concept. But here, though I have pointed the shared memory addresses of different variables to different files, they seem to be connected. As soon as I alter value of one variable, the new value overwrites on other variable too, in this case, se1->val and se2->val are coming out to be connected. Can someone help why it's happening so?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#define s(t) scanf("%d",&t)
#define p(t) printf("%d ",t)
struct sem
{
    int val;
    int xy;
};
struct sem* se1;
struct sem* se2;
int main()
{
    printf("You in P1\n");
    key_t key1,key2;
    key1=ftok("shmfile1",0);
    key2=ftok("shmfile3",0);
    int shmid1=shmget(key1, sizeof(struct sem),0644|IPC_CREAT);
    int shmid2=shmget(key2, sizeof(struct sem),0644|IPC_CREAT);
    se1=shmat(shmid1,NULL,0);
    se2=shmat(shmid2,NULL,0);
    se1->xy=4;
    se2->xy=8;
    se1->val=0;
    se2->val=1;
    int r=10;
    while(r--)
    {
        printf("\nIn P1 process ");
        while(se2->val==0);
        se2->val--;
        se1->xy=se2->xy+1;
        se1->val++;
        p(se1->xy);
        p(se2->xy);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is expected se1->val and se2->val will lead to semaphore type results, but due to overwriting it's not happening!

Comment: I'd start by checking the return values of all your functions for errors instead of assuming they all succeed.